# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: BAD_LENGTH] bad length (_ssl.c:2485) on Paho-Mqtt Python with Multithreading

Tags: python, linux, ssl, mqtt, python-multithreading

I am using the paho-mqtt==1.6.1 python library on ubuntu to a cloud broker with TLS enabled. A client is created in the main.py file:

```
client = mqtt.Client(client_id=f'{config["barge_name"]}_scc_primary')
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.will_set(f"SENTINEL/{config['barge_name']}/{config['barge_mcu']}/STATUS", lastwillmsg,retain=True)

client.tls_set("/etc/ssl/certs/ISRG_Root_X1.pem")
client.ws_set_options({"enable_multithread": True})
client.username_pw_set(username=config['mqtt_username'], password=config['mqtt_password'])
client.connect(config['mqtt_ip'], config['mqtt_port'], config['keep_alive'])

dispatcher.addHandler("HEALTH",handlers.publishHealthStats,(client,),interval=intervals["HEALTH"])
dispatcher.addHandler("STEMS",handlers.publishStems,(client,),interval=intervals["STEMS"])
client.loop_forever()
```

The dispatcher object acts as a class that pumps some data via mqtt at specific intervals. It starts daemon threads that run on infinite loop as shown below:

```
def addHandler(self,handler_name,handler,args:tuple,interval=30):
        self.handlers[handler_name] = handler
        self.intervals[handler_name] = interval
        self.args[handler_name] = args
        self.flag[handler_name] = True
        d = threading.Thread(target=self.__startLoop,args=(handler_name,))
        d.setDaemon(True)
        d.start()

def __startLoop(self,handler_name):
        handler = self.handlers[handler_name]
        while self.flag[handler_name]:
            interval = self.intervals[handler_name]
            time.sleep(interval)
            handler(*self.args[handler_name])
```

A typical handler function looks like:

```
def publishHealthStats(client):
    data = healthStats()
    data['barge'] = config['barge_id']
    client.publish(f"SENTINEL/{config['barge_name']}/{config['barge_mcu']}/HEALTH", dumps(data))
```

Till here everything was running perfectly fine for months till I set TLS on Mqtt. Now sometimes some threads (handlers) fail with the following error:

```
Mar 30 09:37:52 mcu124 python3[1639772]:     return self.loop_write()
Mar 30 09:37:52 mcu124 python3[1639772]:   File "/home/sentinel/scc_onboard/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py>
Mar 30 09:37:52 mcu124 python3[1639772]:     rc = self._packet_write()
Mar 30 09:37:52 mcu124 python3[1639772]:   File "/home/sentinel/scc_onboard/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py>
Mar 30 09:37:52 mcu124 python3[1639772]:     write_length = self._sock_send(
Mar 30 09:37:52 mcu124 python3[1639772]:   File "/home/sentinel/scc_onboard/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py>
Mar 30 09:37:52 mcu124 python3[1639772]:     return self._sock.send(buf)
Mar 30 09:37:52 mcu124 python3[1639772]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1173, in send
Mar 30 09:37:52 mcu124 python3[1639772]:     return self._sslobj.write(data)
Mar 30 09:37:52 mcu124 python3[1639772]: ssl.SSLError: [SSL: BAD_LENGTH] bad length (_ssl.c:2485)
```

Can someone suggest a fix? Went through https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/451 but not able to understand where to use the option with paho-mqtt library?p

Comment: I don't think threading is the issue here; calling `publish` does not actually send anything; the messages [are queued](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/9782ab81fe7ee3a05e74c7f3e1d03d5611ea4be4/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L2693) and sent [from the loop](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/9782ab81fe7ee3a05e74c7f3e1d03d5611ea4be4/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L1181) - this means that messages should be sent from one thread. Can you please show how you are running the `loop` (are you using `loop_start()`)?

Comment: client.loop_forever()